# Asynchronous JK Flip-Flop in VHDL

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, flipflop

and thanks for your help.

I wrote the code for an Asynchronous JK Flip Flop in VHDL, the code is the following:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity ffjk is
port(
    J,K: in std_logic;
    Q,NQ: buffer std_logic
);
end ffjk;
architecture flipflop of ffjk is
begin
    process (J,K)
    begin
    if J ='0' and K='0' then 
        Q <= Q;
        NQ <= NOT Q;
        end if;
    if J ='0' and K='1' then 
        Q <= '0';
        NQ <= '1';
        end if;
    if J ='1' and K='0' then 
        Q <= '1';
        NQ <= '0';
        end if;
    if J ='1' and K='1' then 
        Q <= NOT Q;
        NQ <= NOT Q;
        end if;

    end process; 
end flipflop;
```

Once compiled, the code reacts as expected to all signals except the toggle signal, then the flip flop behaves like an SR latch in forbidden state.
Perhaps a simulation diagram might help explain my problem:

[image: Simulation, please pay special attention to the case when J=1 K=1]

I have checked my code several time but I couldn't find any mistakes.

How do I get the flip flop to behave properly? What have I done wrong?

Thanks again

Comment: This design is a disaster; there's no code that can safely implement an unsafe design.  (In particular, there's nothing in a "JK latch" that controls the *rate* of toggling.  And flip-flops are synchronous by definition, every JK flip-flop has a clock.)

Comment: The only sensible answer to this question is *why?* You seem to be trying to construct transistor level functionality from standard cells, but presenting it as a solution to a synchronous truth table problem. You've indirectly answered the question 'why are HDLs so poor for describing synthesisable designs'.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten that the *concurrent* assignment in VHDL is actually working *concurrently*. So these lines:

```
Q <= NOT Q;
NQ <= NOT Q;
```

Will take the *previous value* of `Q`, invert it and assign to *both* `Q` and `NQ`. Probably you might want to replace the second line by

```
 NQ <= NOT NQ;
```

Comment: I've made the change accordingly, the simulation seems to run as expected, however when I try the code on my FPGA board, the toggle signal turns both outputs to high, is there any reason this happens?

Comment: Of course. See @BenVoigt comment. This design is not good for anything other than simulation. In the simulation the process is triggered by the change in the sensitivity list signals, so it works. But in the real metal there is no such a mechanism, so it will just be unstable. You have to make it synchronous.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Is there any nice way to specify a device that will work like a real JK flip-flop chip with async set/reset inputs, such that the output will behave cleanly in all cases where any input events that would have timing constraints on the real chip are widely separated, but input events which wouldn't affect the output need not be (e.g. if the output is stable low, K and /Reset may switch arbitrarily close to the clock without affecting the output)?

Comment: Of course there is a way. You can easily find numerous examples online (don't fixate on JK, but any FF and you can change the behavior yourself).

Comment: @supercat: Well, there may be hazard-free designs, but the synthesis-to-FPGA process doesn't implement exactly what's written, it must transform it to the actual cells inside the FPGA, and while it preserves logical correctness in the process, things like delay are not.  If your FPGA has real D flip-flops in the cells (very common), then you can get hazard-free D flip-flop behavior... but even if you write a description of a hazard-free J/K flip-flop, constraint on your control signals are determined by the timing behavior of (typically) a lookup-table that the FPGA uses for all combinational.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's possible to construct LUT modules that are free of logic hazards; making large LUTs completely free of hazards would be very expensive, but adding enough circuitry to partially guard them shouldn't be, and I would think given such devices it should be possible for synthesis tools to ensure that signals that needed to be glitch-free, were.  If one can't, by what means could one avoid needing some discrete logic outside an FPGA in cases where it needs to interface with real-world devices that require glitch-free signals?